# jqwidgets angular 2 integration, can not find module?

Tags: angular, jqwidget

I'm following the jqwidgets' angular 2 examples. But I can't import the jqwidget module to my app.

The folder structure:

```
/root
    /Scripts
        /JQwidgets
            /jqwidgets-ts
                ...
                angular_jqxinput.ts
                ...
    /app
        ...(components)...
        /app.module.ts
        /main.ts
    /index.html
    /package.json
    /tsconfig.json
    /systemjs.config.js
```

Related config in the systemjs.config.js file:

```
map: {
      app: 'app',          

      // angular bundles
      ...

      // other libraries
      ...
      'components': './Scripts/JQWidgets/jqwidgets-ts/'          
    },

packages: {
      ...
      './Scripts/JQWidgets/jqwidgets-ts/': {
          defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
      app: {
        main: 'main.js',        
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
      ...
    }
```

I believe this is effectively the same as the example from jqwidgets site.

Now when I do this in the app.module.ts:

```
import { jqxInputComponent } from 'components/angular_jqxinput';
```

It doesn't work and the error from visual studio 2015 is "can't find module 'components/angular_jqxinput'".

Can anyone provide some insight about this problem?

NOTE: the app works fine before I try to pull in jqwidgets. no error about angular 2 or the components I created.